# How do I make java game options?

Tags: java

I m trying to make a main menu with START button, CONTROLS button and HELP button.
I made a backboard for it but I need help with making options.
I tried to make it, but the error says that local variable gameFrame is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class GameFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("PoopMan");
        gameFrame.setSize(900, 800);
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.setResizable(false);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        gameFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        gameFrame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gameFrame.getComponent(0), "START");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything in terms of making the options?

Comment: Sounds like that error your report is telling you exactly what you need to do: make the `gameFrame` variable final if you want to read it from an inner class, or modify the inner class so that the variable can be passed/injected via a setter or constructor.

Comment: what is an inner class?

Answer (score 0):

That is quite simple. Please note that this is a place to inquire about issues regarding your code, and not a place to look for answers.

What you should be researching is known as JMenuBar (refer to [This Tutorial for Assitance)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0400__JMenuBar.htm)

Seeing as you are new, I will assist you this once. Below is the code that will accomplish what you ask. (Tried and Tested)

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class GameFrame
{
    static private JMenuBar menuBar;
    static private JMenu startMenu, controlsMenu, helpMenu;
    static private JMenuItem startBtn;
    static private JMenuItem controls;
    static private JMenuItem hlpBtn;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("PoopMan");

        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        gameFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        startMenu = new JMenu("File");
        controlsMenu = new JMenu("Controls");
        helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

        startBtn = new JMenuItem("Start");
        controls = new JMenuItem("Controls");
        hlpBtn = new JMenuItem("Help");

        gameFrame.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        menuBar.add(startMenu);
        menuBar.add(controlsMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        startMenu.add(startBtn);
        controlsMenu.add(controls);
        helpMenu.add(hlpBtn);

        gameFrame.pack();
        gameFrame.setResizable(false);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        gameFrame.setSize(900,800);
    }
}
```

I am not certain as to why you are receiving a Final error. It works fine.

From later edits to the question:

```
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        gameFrame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gameFrame.getComponent(0), "START");
            }
        });
```

---

[image: Updated Proof]

[image: Proof]

Comment: Options show on the left cornor. Instead I want it show in the middle of the frame. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: So you want the menu, but in the middle?

Comment: There is no way to do that. We can maybe align it to the right of the screen. But if you want options in the middle of the screen my only suggestion is that you use buttons as menu links perhaps

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to initialize your Game in a non-static context. Do the following.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GameFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    private void init() {
        this.setSize(900, 800);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("START");
        this.add(panel);
        panel.add(button1);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getComponent(0), "START");
            }
        });
    }

    public GameFrame() {
        super("PoopMan");
        init();
    }
}
```

This way, you start the GameFrame on another thread, and you can continue your work within the `GameFrame` class.